# Spreadsheets.get returns 404 on fetching selected document

Tags: google-api, google-sheets-api

We have web and desktop app. In both, we:

1. Get access token
2. Display Google Document Picker
3. Call Spreadsheets.get API to get selected document (`https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/<document-id>?includeGridData=true`)

For the desktop app, Spreadsheets.get API  returns 404.
At the same time, for web version it returns document contents, as expected.
And after document is imported in web version, import in the desktop app (of the same document) is not failing anymore.

The code for fetching a document is common for both applications.

The difference is in getting security token.
For web version, token is obtained using JS Google API (gapi.auth2.authorize method), and desktop auth is based on `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth` page.

On every import attempt the new token is being obtained.

Scope: `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file`

Does anyone have any idea what may be the cause?

Comment: Could you please provide the code related to the OAuth process? How did you create this file? Please be aware that `drive.file` only give you access to `files and folders that you have opened or created with this app`.

Comment: `drive.file` is what I need: only have access to files, user selected. solved it by specifying app id in PickerBuilder. thank you for trying to help!

Answer (score 0):

Resolved.
I simply forgot to specify app id for the Document Picker in the desktop app ‍♂️